# How do I extract beginning/ending points for polyline shapes?

Tags: arcmap, feature-extraction

I need to extract the beginning/ending coordinates of every shape within a polyline shapefile. It would be best to actually add them as values within the shapefiles .dbf (I can live without doing this).

What is the easiest way to do this in ArcMap? I know that XTools has a plugin that does this really easy, but I don't want to purchase software for something that seems like it should be fairly trivial.

I am currently using ArcMap 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be readily done using the field calculator as outlined in [the online help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000025000000.htm)  you can get the first and last point's x and y coordinates added to your table.  If you need to produce a shapefile from them then you will have additional steps

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find it after some research in there. What helped out the most was when I realized how to use the CalculateGeometry function within the Attributes Table.

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying which version of ArcMap you are using but in either 9 or 10 you should be able to use the field calculator. In 10 you can also use Python scripting as well as vb script. Have a look [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Making_field_calculations) for 9 and [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp00000015000000.htm) for 10

Answer (score -1):

This is a free feature of X=Tools so no purchase necessary.